# referring wrong db while using multiple db connections in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I loaded two different database in Codeigniter controllers `_contruct` in series. While I call the second database in action it works fine but first loaded db is referring second loaded db.

```
function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();  

 $this->liveDB = $this->load->database('liveDB', TRUE);
 $this->metricsDB = $this->load->database('metricsDB', TRUE);
}
```

My Action

```
$this->metricsDB->query("") // working good

$this->liveDB->query("") // referring database metricsDB
```

Note : If I change the order in **__construct** it works opposite

Comment: do you have your database set to autoload, if so what happens when you turn autoload database off?

Comment: @allen213: I tried removing 'database' from autoload. Still same

Comment: Have you put the right config entries for each in the database.php config file?

Comment: I'd imagine he has, as he states: " If I change the order in __construct it works opposite".

Comment: Have you tried any of the advice here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634291/codeigniter-using-multiple-databases?rq=1 ?

Comment: @allen213: Thanks for the link I turned of pconnect it works

Comment: No problem. For future reference it may have been suggested as you were writing your question

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by persistent connect, set

```
$db['livDB']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['metricsDB']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

in your database config see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CI User guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html):

If you need to connect to more than one database simultaneously you can do so as follows:

```
$liveDB = $this->load->database('liveDB', TRUE);
$metricsDB = $this->load->database('metricsDB', TRUE);
```

Then you can use:

```
$metricsDB->query();
$metricsDB->result();
```

Comment: Make sure a database is not set to `autoload` -> `application/config/autoload.php`. As @allen213 mentioned.