# Codeigniter - How can I connect ORACLE, MySQL and SQL Server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, oracle11g

I have found many questions regarding connecting multiple databases like this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634291/codeigniter-using-multiple-databases) which helps in connecting multiple databases of MYSQL. In my case i need to connect to MySQL, ORACLE and SQL Server in same application.

Is it even possible using codeigniter Active Records?

I have googled a lot, but was unable to find any answer. It was a big surprise for me that no one faced similar problem.

Comment: `PDO` allows to connect to any DBMS type.

Comment: Thanks Begueradj for you Answer, But does PDO gives power to connect to all these DBMS in one Application?

Comment: Of course you can, no problem for that. Please check any tutorial on how `PDO` works and you will guess you can do that.

Comment: Thanks Bedueradj, but i figured out how to do this all without using PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the trick to do this in codeigniter, there are actually three very important things to keep in mind:

1. You should have the client installed on your Apache e.g. SQL
   SERVER client
2. Your "pconnect" should be set to FALSE in config/database.php file
3. To use your sqlserver(2nd Connection) you have to use below code in your
   constructor or function in which you want to use:

$this->sqlsrvr = $this->load->database('test', true);

**Example Database.php File**

You have to add multiple entries in your database.php file config folder, i am sharing my test database.php file below:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'jawad';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; 

$db['test']['hostname'] = "192.168.43.104";
$db['test']['username'] = "sa";
$db['test']['password'] = "password";
$db['test']['database'] = "jawad";
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = "sqlsrv";
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['test']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```