# Multiple databases connectivity issue Grocery Crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Thanks in advance. i am trying to connect to another db(second database which is configured in database config file) but when i try to connect it using.

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('db2',true);
```

but it is querying the default database. **grocery_crud** does not provide any **function** set **database**. i am clueless at the moment that how to fix it.

Comment: is it possible to share screen shot of error?

Comment: we are unable to share...because default database has the same table name ''my_products"..so it is getting records from there

Comment: this would might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634291/codeigniter-using-multiple-databases

Comment: this would might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634291/codeigniter-using-multiple-databases
as it a duplicate question