# How can i insert data into two MySql tables on a single click?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How can i insert data into two MySql tables on a single click ?

**model code**

```
public function insertCSV($data)                                                                                                                    
{                                                            
    $this->db->insert('question_tb', $data);
    $this->db->insert('option_tb', $data);
    return TRUE;
}
```

**controller code**

```
public function import(){
    if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
        $this->load->model('Welcome_model', 'welcome');
        $exam_id = $this->welcome->get_max_exam_id();
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];


        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== false) {

                $data = [
                    'question' => $importdata[0],
                    'answer'  => $importdata[1],
                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                ];

                while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== false) {
                    $data = [
                        'option1' => $importdata[2],
                        'option2' => $importdata[3],
                        'option3' => $importdata[4],
                        'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                    ];

                    $insert = $this->welcome->insertCSV($data);
                }
                //fclose($file);


                fclose($file);
                redirect('upload/index');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing? What is not working? Please add some more background to your original question.

Comment: You need add the second mysql connection. You can reference this https://stackoverflow.com/q/634291/685060

Comment: data only inserting in question_tb(table)  but i want to insert data in question_tb(table) & answer_tb(table) on a single click after uploading .csv file,

Comment: Please ask question the way other people can understand. What is the error you see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options

1. Create two functions in the model and call those function in the controller.

Model:

```
function a($data1){
   $this->db->insert('table1', $data1);
}

function b($data2){
   $this->db->insert('table2', $data2);
}
```

Controller :

```
function insert(){
  $this->model_name->a($data1);
  $this->model_name->b($data2);
}
```

2. Create a function in the model and pass two array data

Model:

```
function a($data1, $data2){
   $this->db->insert('table1', $data1);
   $this->db->insert('table2', $data2);
}
```

Controller:

```
function insert(){
  $this->model_name->a($data1, $data2);
}
```